# JPA nested composite PK

Tags: java, jpa

I'm trying to configure the JPA classes for the following PK requirements:

---

A **Writer** class / table with a PK of *[Long id]*, for example [1], [2], [3]...

A **Book** class / table with a composite PK of *[Writer Long id and Long index]* (thus each writer has his own book indexes), for example [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3] (three books for writer #1), [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4] (four books for writer #2)...

A **Page** class / table with a composite PK of *[Writer Long id, Book Long index and Long number]* (thus each book has its own page numbers), for example [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 4], [1, 1, 5] (five pages for writer #1 and his book index #1)...

---

What I need from a Book instance is to be able to call **book.getWriter()** and get a Writer instance; also, **page.getBook()** would return a Book instance. Of course, ALL three classes could easily have a simple Long PK and then, for example, a book would have the Writer as a not-nullable, @ManyToOne association outside the PK, but it doesn't suite our needs.

---

I've exhausted any configuration using @Embedded(|Id), @Embeddable, @IdClass, @MapsId, etc. I could think of or Googled, but Hibernate would always complain one way or the other, especially about the **Page** class where things are getting “**nested**”. Ideally, a later **Paragraph** class / table with a composite PK of *[Writer Long id, Book Long index, Page Long number and Long paragraph index]* should be configured likewise.

---

I hope someone has any good hints about this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simple example using ID classes:

```
@Entity
Class Writer {
  @ID Long id;
}
@Entity
@IdClass(BookId.class)
Class Book{
  @ID Long index;
  @ID Writer writer;
}
Class BookId{
  Long index;
  Long writer;
}
@Entity
@IdClass(PageId.class)
Class Page{
  @ID Long number;
  @ID Book book;
}
Class PageId{
  Long number;
  BookId book;
}
```

basically, what do you want your model to look like?